# Laravel, get id from an <a> link

Tags: php, html, laravel

How to get user id properly?, This is error message `Missing required parameter for [Route: user.currentRequest] [URI: user/user-current-request/{user}] [Missing parameter: user]`

An `User` has many relationship with `Request`, and the url will be `user-current-request{user-id}`

```
//layouts.app

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('user.currentRequest') }}">Current Request</a>
</li>
```

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'user', 'middleware'=>['isUser','auth']], function(){

    Route::get('user-current-request/{user}', [UserController::class, 'currentRequest'])->name('user.currentRequest');
});
```

```
    function currentRequest(User $user)
    {
        dd($user);

        return view('dashboards.users.currentRequest');
    }
```

Comment: The documentation on [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route in Layouts.app need params.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('user.currentRequest', $user) }}">Current Request</a>
</li>
```

If you want to give this params in layout you have to do it in the providers / appserviceprovider